# ¿Cómo ubicar en una sola fila 3 elementos con propiedades bootstrap y css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy teniendo un problema para alinear estos div en fila, ya que uno de ellos se va para el lado de abajo. Ya intenté de todo, pero de cualquier forma no se quedan en fila.

Tengo 3 elementos con una imagen cada uno, y necesito que los 3 formen una fila. Cuando inserto el 3er elemento, se va para el lado de abajo y la idea es que estén los 3 uno al lado del otro.
Este es el código HTML y el CSS que estoy usando actualmente.
Usando version Bootstrap v3.2.0
Tengo 3 elementos con una imagen cada uno, y necesito que los 3 formen una fila. Cuando inserto el 3er elemento, se va para el lado de abajo y la idea es que estén los 3 uno al lado del otro.
Este es el código HTML y el CSS que estoy usando actualmente.
Usando version Bootstrap v3.2.0

```css
    .bg-color-gray{background:#f4f4f4;padding-bottom:10px;}
    .bg-color-gray h2{font-family:ubuntu condensed;color:#015f9e;margin-top:10px;font-size:28px;}
    .bg-color-gray p{color:#757374;font-size:13px}
    .form-consulta label{color:#878585;font-size:12px;font-weight:100;}
    .box-cc{padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;}
    .box-cc-form .bg-color-gray{min-height:380px;}
    .box-sucu{background:#FFF;margin:35px 0px;padding:0px;}
    .box-barracas{justify-content: center;}
    .box-sucu-img{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
    .box-sucu-img p img{width:194px;height:241px;}
    .box-sucu-img p{text-align:right;margin:0px;}
    .titulo-secs{color:#005F9E;font-size:22px;font-family:"ubuntu condensed";}
```

```html
 <main>
    <div class="container-fluid lcf-container">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="box-secs">
            <div class="col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="nl-mayoristas-pic" style="height: 405px;">
                    <img class="nl-mayoristas-pic-float" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/img_empresa-shop.jpg') ?>" alt="empresa">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 sec-fija-content">
                <h1>ESPECIALISTAS EN EQUIPOS FITNESS</h1>
                <h2>Trabajamos diariamente para brindarte <span style="font-weight: 700;">los mejores productos y servicios</span></h2>
                <h3>Somos la empresa de equipos fitness más importante del país y nos dedicamos exclusivamente a este rubro.</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Nos respalda una larga trayectoria en el mercado, la cual incluye sucursales propias y distintos representantes oficiales en todo el país.</li>
                    <li>Ofrecemos la más amplia variedad de equipos fitness de uso residencial, nivel semi profesional o profesional.</li>
                    <li>Cubrimos todo tipo de necesidades en lo que concierne al cuidado del cuerpo y la salud, y trabajamos con equipamiento para complementar las rutinas de ejercicio.</li>
                    <li style="font-weight: 700;">Nuestra larga trayectoria en el mercado, junto a la dedicación exclusiva al rubro, nos permite garantizar el mejor servicio de venta y posventa.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-color-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box-sucu pull-left">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <h1 class="titulo-secs">
                                SUCURSAL
                                <br>
                                VILLA CRESPO
                            </h1>
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/villa-crespo'); ?>" class="btn btn-info pull-left  btn-vermas">VER INFO <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-xs-6 box-sucu-img">
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/villa-crespo'); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/sucursales/capitalfederal.jpg'); ?>" alt="sucursal-01" class=""></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12   col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box-sucu pull-left">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6  col-xs-6">
                            <h1 class="titulo-secs">
                                SUCURSAL
                                <br>
                                BOEDO
                            </h1>
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/boedo'); ?>" class="btn btn-info pull-left  btn-vermas">VER INFO <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-6   col-xs-6 box-sucu-img">
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/boedo'); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/sucursales/sucursal_boedo.jpg'); ?>" alt="sucursal-01" class=""> </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="box-sucu pull-left">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <h1 class="titulo-secs">
                                SUCURSAL
                                <br>
                                BARRACAS
                            </h1>
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/barracas'); ?>" class="btn btn-info pull-left  btn-vermas">VER INFO <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-xs-6 box-sucu-img">
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/barracas'); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/sucursales/barracas.jpg'); ?>" alt="sucursal-01" class=""></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-12   col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-sucu pull-left">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  col-xs-6">
                    <h1 class="titulo-secs">
                        CENTRAL<br> DE LOGÍSTICA
                        <br>
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/outlet'); ?>" class="btn btn-info pull-left  btn-vermas">VER INFO <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6   col-xs-6 box-sucu-img">
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/outlet'); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/sucursales/central.jpg'); ?>" alt="sucursal-01" class=""> </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nl-footer-marcas-bg ">
        <div class="container-fluid lcf-container">
            <div class="nl-logos">
                <img src="https://nl.lacasadelfitness.com/assets/img/logos_footer.png" class="img-responsive center-block hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="Randers Zellens Fitage Corplus Omiko BH Embreex Ziva Athletic FitHouse">
                <img src="https://nl.lacasadelfitness.com/assets/img/logos_footer_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block hidden-md hidden-lg" alt="Randers Zellens Fitage Corplus Omiko BH Embreex Ziva Athletic FitHouse">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas indicando que cada una de las columnas utilice 6 espacios de las 12 que provee bootstrap. La solución es cambiar de 6 a 4. Por otra parte te hace falta agregar la clase `row` dentro del container.

El HTML debe quedar así:

```
<div class="bg-color-gray">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aquí te comparto el html completo y una imagen de referencia

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .bg-color-gray{background:#f4f4f4;padding-bottom:10px;}
        .bg-color-gray p{color:#757374;font-size:13px}
        .box-sucu-img img{width:194px;height:241px;}
    </style>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="bg-color-gray">
        <div class="container">        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="bg-white my-5 p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h1 class="fs-1 text-uppercase text-wrap">sucursal <br> villa crespo</h1>
                                <p>Venta de equipos fitness</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-info">
                                    Ver Info
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 ps-0 box-sucu-img">
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/villa-crespo'); ?>"> 
                                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="sucursal-01" class="w-100">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="bg-white my-5 p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h1 class="fs-1 text-uppercase text-wrap">sucursal <br> BOEDO</h1>
                                <p>Venta de equipos fitness</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-info">
                                    Ver Info
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 ps-0 box-sucu-img">
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/villa-crespo'); ?>"> 
                                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="sucursal-01" class="w-100">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="bg-white my-5 p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h1 class="fs-1 text-uppercase text-wrap">sucursal <br> BARRACAS</h1>
                                <p>Venta de equipos fitness
                                    Especial Outlet</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-info">
                                    Ver Info
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 ps-0 box-sucu-img">
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('' . $ubicacion . '/sucursal/villa-crespo'); ?>"> 
                                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="sucursal-01" class="w-100">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que cuando quiero darle un espaciado entre cada div para que no quede todo junto y pegado uno al lado del otro, vuelve a quedarse el 3er div abajo!

Comment: No me queda asi, se sigue yendo para abajo

Comment: Comparte tu HTML completo, a lo mejor alguna otra etiqueta estará afectando.

Comment: Ahi modifique la publicacion, con el html completo, asi lo tengo en este momento.

Comment: Que versión de Bootstrap estas usando?

Comment: Era la version de bootstrap!! Muchas graciaas GFlores98, idolo!

Comment: Para el autor de la respuesta: si la edición a tu respuesta en realidad es un comentario, **no aceptes la edición**. Para OP (@SebasF): ¡ya no intentes responder con una edición! Por cierto, edita tu pregunta y pon qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando. Recuerda que tu pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser de utilidad no solo para ti, sino también para otros usuarios que lleguen a tener un problema similar.